Why do JavaScript arrays behave differently in async functions?
Why do the following functions log different values to the console, and how can I modify the asynchronous function to log ‘3’ like the synchronous function?


const delay = (ms) => new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, ms));
const a = [1, 2, 3];

function testSync() {
  let b = [];
  a.forEach((element) => {
    b.push(element);
  });
  console.log(b.length);
}

async function testAsync() {
  let c = [];
  a.forEach(async(element) => {
    await delay(1);
    c.push(element);
  });
  console.log(c.length);
}

testSync();
testAsync();



I expected both functions to log the same number.

The function passed to forEach is not executed with await (i.e., it's not forEach(await (async (element) => { ... } ))), so the forEach runs without waiting for the push to happen, and you end up with an empty array immediately. If you add an await delay(3); after the forEach, you might see the same length.
